Python Kivy Android app and Pyjnius autoclass FFMPEG
I've been trying to make an Android app on Python3.12 and Kivy.
It's been a smooth ride until I tried to download a video with yt-dlp on an actual Android device.
Turns out it can't just use FFMPEG to convert the videos like that.
My understanding is that the only way for yt-dlp to use FFMPEG is by compiling it along with the app, for which I came across https://github.com/ArqiesAr/FFmpeg-Kit-Python#3-using-with-python .
But as I am completely unfamiliar with Java, I can't figure out how to implement this into my code, and the README there I just don't completely get.
As first steps provide steps to install SDK/NDK and modify the Buildozer.spec.
My understanding was that I will need Buildozer only after I write my Python code and want to compile it as an Android APK to run on the Android device.
Also, I'm completely confused with their Python usage:
#IMPORTING jnius
from jnius import autoclass
from jnius import * 
#Declaring Variable so it can be used
FFMPEG = autoclass('com.sahib.pyff.ffpy')

as it will return error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\...\kivy_project\main.py", line 30, in <module>
     FFMPEG = autoclass('com.sahib.pyff.ffpy')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jnius\reflect.py", line 209, in autoclass
     c = find_javaclass(clsname)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "jnius\\jnius_export_func.pxi", line 22, in jnius.find_javaclass
   File "jnius\\jnius_utils.pxi", line 79, in jnius.check_exception
 jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: com/sahib/pyff/ffpy java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

With some help from chatgpt I came to an understanding that I need some java classes at my
parent/com/sahib/pyff/ffpy, but I just don't understand at all which and where to get them from.
Also the README says:

Building (Skip this part, its for myself lol) Run android.sh at
project root directory to build ffmpeg-kit and ffmpeg shared
libraries.

So I'm not supposed to build anything, just get some files from the Git itself?
Can someone please explain, I'm really at a loss here.

I don't know if yt-dlp can download without converting because it would allow to download without conversion and later use subprocess() to execute ffmpeg like subprocess.run("ffmpeg -i input_file output_file", shell=True)

@furas that would require for the end user to have ffmpeg installed on their device tho. Assuming that subprocess can be called on Android.

I think yt-dlp also needs presintalled ffmpeg and kivy will also needs preinstalled ffmpeg - so always you will have to find method to add ffmpeg with your code. And I think yt-dlp may use subprocess to run ffmpeg. But I never test it and I didn't check source code to see subprocess. On Androind I use termux (special terminal) and it allowed me to install ffmpeg - so they have precompiled version.
